# MySQLI echo data from database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating a website and I am using mySqli to connect to the database. For some reason when I try to echo the information from the database I am not getting anything returning. I need it to take a column from the table and display it on the page, this isn't happening. I have asked someone else and they thought it was strange (we spent about 1 hour trying to fix it) so any help would greatly appreciated.

postimg.org/image/qqv4vmtf7
postimg.org/image/rp6hhz8ht

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }

    $condition = empty($_POST['sender']) || empty($_POST['reciever']);
    if (!$condition) {
        $name = $_POST['sender'];       
        $reciever = $_POST['reciever'];

        $query = "UPDATE users SET userCoins = userCoins + 1  WHERE userName='Morgan'";
        $res = $mysqli->query($query);
        if ($res) {
            $error = "Success!";
        } else {
            $error = "Something Went Wrong!";
            echo "Error: ".$mysqli->error; // here you can check your errors
        }
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']; 
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        $userRow = $result->fetch_assoc();
if (!$userRow) {
    die("userID {$_SESSION['user']} not found!");
}
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.py69.esy.es"); ?>
    <head>
        <title>ServiceCoin</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"  />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/home/index.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="a">ServiceCoin.com(image)</a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php?logout" class="a">Sign Out</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="a">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="a">Get Service Coins</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="a">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="settings.php" class="a">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="a">Referrals</a></li>
            <li><a href="service.php" class="a">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="home.php" class="a">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br /><br />
        <center>
        <h3>Welcome, <?php echo $userRow['userName']; ?>. You Currently Have <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><span id="services"><?php var_dump($userRow) ?></span> Service Coins</h3>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-lock"></span></span>
                    <input type="text" name="sender" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Wallet Key" maxlength="15" />
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $error; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-lock"></span></span>
                    <input type="text" name="reciever" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter The Recievers Wallet Key" maxlength="15" />
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $error; ?></span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="send">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: You need to call `$result->fetch_assoc()` to get a row of results. Any tutorial on using mysqli should show this.

Comment: Where do you set `$userRow`?

Comment: Look edit, I still don't know how to echo the column to the page.

Comment: You need to assign it to something, like `$userRow = $result->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: If you'd bothered to read a single tutorial, or the examples in the PHP documentation, you'd have seen this.

Comment: I have put it into a variable and have called it <?php echo $userRow; ?> but still I am receiving nothing

Comment: `$userRow` is an array. `echo $userRow['userName'];` should work.

Comment: I am still receiving nothing

Comment: Don't change the question to match the answer.

Comment: What does `var_dump($userRow);` show?

Comment: It says: NULL .

Comment: Because you never set `$result`. You should have gotten an error from calling `$result->fetch_assoc();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not executing the `SELECT` query. You need:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']; 
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Then change:

```
$result->fetch_assoc();
```

to

```
$userRow = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Then you can use things like `$userRow['userName']` and `$userRow['userCoins']` to show information about the user.

You should also check if the query found anything, like:

```
if (!$userRow) {
    die("userID {$_SESSION['user']} not found!");
}
```

The code that performs the `SELECT` query and sets `$userRow` should not be in the `if(!$condition)` block, so that you'll see the user information when you view the page before submitting the form.

Comment: I have done everything on here but i am still receiving nothing.

Comment: That can't be. `fetch_assoc()` returns either an array or `FALSE`, it never returns `NULL`.

Comment: That's `$userRow['userKey']`, not `var_dump($userRow)`.

Comment: No it isn't take that wasn't doing anything if you look

Comment: The image shows the line with `<h3>Welcome, <?php echo $userRow['userName']; ?>. You Currently Have <span id="services"><?php echo $userRow['userKey']; ?></span> Service Coins</h3>`, so `NULL` is where `echo $userRow['userKey'];` is.

Comment: Put `<?php var_dump($userRow);` ?>` on the line before that.

Comment: Are you seeing this after submitting the form? The code that selects from the database is only done when one of the `$_POST` variables is set.

Comment: I am getting this error now: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/u923288908/public_html/coins/send_coins.php on line 17

Comment: Then there's some problem with the code that sets `$mysqli`, which I guess is in `dbconnect.php`.

Comment: <?php
 $con = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "database"); // here you will need your connection data, you can store it in dbconnect.php.
?>

Comment: The variable is `$con`, not `$mysqli`.

Comment: Well... as it turns out i am a pleb. Thank you for helping the problem is now fixed